# Why is my for loop looping infinitely

Tags: for-loop, unity-game-engine

I made two scripts in Unity3D that should check names and count of objects in folder. The thing is, that it is doing it's job infinitely. Don't you know where is the problem?

First Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MenuSetup : MonoBehaviour {


    public static List<Texture2D> UnitIconTextures = new List<Texture2D>();
    public static List<string> UnitNames = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> UnitPaths = new List<string>();


    void OnGUI(){
        for(int i = 0; i < UnitNames.Count; i++){
            Debug.Log (UnitNames[i]);
        }

    }


}
```

Second script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class World : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){
        string path = "Prefabs/Units";  
        Object[] Units = Resources.LoadAll (path);

        if(Units.Length > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < Units.Length; i++){
                GameObject unit = Units[i] as GameObject;
                Texture2D unitIcon = unit.GetComponent<Unit>().MenuIcon;

                MenuSetup.UnitIconTextures.Add (unitIcon);
                MenuSetup.UnitNames.Add (unit.name);
                MenuSetup.UnitPaths.Add (path+"/"+unit.name);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which one is looping infinitely? Have you printed Units to see what's in it on each iteration?

Comment: In my opinion the second script is looping. It is just debugging unit names again and again

EDIT: Actually it is the first one.

Comment: The fact that it's doing that means that it's NOT looping infinitely. If it were doing so then it'd *hang*.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Nothing is looping infinitely. The problem is with this code:

```
void OnGUI(){
    for(int i = 0; i < UnitNames.Count; i++){
        Debug.Log (UnitNames[i]);
    }

}
```

This method might be called **several times** per frame. So that's why you see a lot of debug info. While `Start` method is called only **once**. So actually, in `World` the `Start` method is called once. This method adds all info to `MenuSetup` class only once. And then you call `Debug.Log` on every frame.

Read more info about `OnGUI` on [unity doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html). Also you should read about `Start` method [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html).

**Little suggestion**

Probably you don't need the `if` check in

```
if(Units.Length > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < Units.Length; i++){
        GameObject unit = Units[i] as GameObject;
        Texture2D unitIcon = unit.GetComponent<Unit>().MenuIcon;

        MenuSetup.UnitIconTextures.Add (unitIcon);
        MenuSetup.UnitNames.Add (unit.name);
        MenuSetup.UnitPaths.Add (path+"/"+unit.name);
    }
}
```

Because when `Units.Length == 0` for-block will not be executed. So probably you want to write

```
for(int i = 0; i < Units.Length; i++){
    GameObject unit = Units[i] as GameObject;
    Texture2D unitIcon = unit.GetComponent<Unit>().MenuIcon;

    MenuSetup.UnitIconTextures.Add (unitIcon);
    MenuSetup.UnitNames.Add (unit.name);
    MenuSetup.UnitPaths.Add (path+"/"+unit.name);
}
```

Comment: I made this with one tutorial on internet
http://youtu.be/Ug-CTQUDfdI?list=PLcGWkWha2wFd5Azr14ZJjvfnAmUKM_3E7
This guy is using it, and it is working for him.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why he doesn't experience Console.Log growth. But currently you can click enable "collapse" in unity console. You can skip on this, because in future videos he should use this information not for `Debug.Log`. But seriously, the problem is with OnGUI.

Comment: Yes I made it and it is working. I'm sorry and thank you. But it is really strange, that in his videos it wasn't making infinite loop..